# How to POST values with specific ID from page that displays a list?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on my first django project which is a sport betting app. My models are:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class GameBet(models.Model):
    gameid = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    bet = models.IntegerField(default=None) #values: 1(home win), 0 (draw), 2 (away win)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I am able to save user bets using a single game view, when I pass gameid in url, but that is not very effective.

I created a simple page with list of games with 1 form per game for a start (at the end I would prefer to send all bets with one button):

```
{% for game in games %}
{{ game.id }} | {{ game.home_team }} | {{ game.away_team }} | <form method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}   <input type="submit" value="bet" /> </form>  <br>  {% endfor %}
```

and my form is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        #if request.POST["bet"] == 'bet':

        form = NewBetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bet = form.save(commit=False)
            bet.gameid = [r.id for r in owing_games] #it gives me a list and ValueError Cannot assign "[10, 11, 12]": "GameBet.gameid" must be a "Game" instance.
            bet.userid_id = current_user.id
            bet.bet = form.value()
            bet.save()
```

How can I pass a single game.id in that case?

EDIT: 
I think I can use request.POST.get(something) but I don't know how to pass my {{ game.id }} from template to views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden input field with value as `game.id`.

**Example**:

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{ game.id }}' name='game_id'>
```

Place the above html code within the `form` block. Now, you can access the value in the `view` as `request.POST['game_id']`.

And, if you want to place same bet for multiple game ids, then loop over game ids, retrieve the `Game` instance from database and assign each new `GameBet` instance `gameid` as the retrieved `Game` instance.

**Single Game ID Example**:

```
game_id = request.POST['game_id']
if request.method == 'POST':
    # rest of the code
    if form.is_valid():
        bet.game_id = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
```

**Multiple Game IDs Example**:

```
game_ids = request.POST['game_ids']
if request.method == 'POST':
    for game_id in game_ids:
        bet = form.save(commit=False)
        bet.game_id = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        bet.save()
    # return response after loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sahin, the single game ID solution works great!